# Excel copying data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Good day

I have workbook A and B. In both workbooks the common column is the ID number however the data in both workbooks are different.

Eg: Workbook A: Column A=Id number, column B= position, colum C= Org Unit Workbook B: Column A: Id number, column B: Bursary number, column C: Bursary Value.

Not all the ID numbers are in workbook B however i want to copy all the data in workbook B to Workbook A into columns D & E corresponding to whichever ID numbers are in workbook B i.e. if there are 500 id numbers in A but only 390 in B then the copy must only update the 390 from work b into workook A.

I hope this makes sense.

Tried vlookup however if you delete book B then the data is not there anymore.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if vlookup works, and you don't need to update the data in workbook B, then just copy and paste as values (removes formula) before deleting the workbook if you have to delete the workbook for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must ensure the two workbooks are saved in the same folder to make the deletion of workbook 2 stop.

Second, to copy the data into workbook A from B try do this

1. In workbook A insert two new columns. D1 = "Bursary number" and E1 = "Bursary Value"
2. In cell D2 of workbook A insert the following formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, '[Workbook B.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$1000, 2, FALSE), "")`

NOTE: when you click enter a new pop-up window will open and that is where you select the other workbook. - Make sure to update the formula so the name matches

3. In cell E2 of workbook A insert the following formula `=IF(D2<>"", VLOOKUP(A2, '[Workbook B.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$1000, 3, FALSE), "")`
   Note This formula uses the same VLOOKUP function as the previous formula but returns the value in the third column of the range "$A$2:$C$1000" (which is the Bursary Value column in Workbook B) if the corresponding Bursary Number in column D is not empty.

The `IFERROR`function helps preventing any errors in later functions if the `N/A`occours while doing `VLOOKUP`.